# The LINQ expression 'Expression' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql

I have looked at a lot of similar questions but none could give me a solution so I am thinking if anyone can help me with this problem. I have a hierarchy  of entities as Clients have multiple ClientRateDeals and then I am trying to fetch only those clients that have a list of client rate deals that all pass some condition. Here's my LINQ query that generating an error :

```
            var query = _context.Client.Where(c=>c.Disabled==false)
                  .GroupJoin(_context.ClientRateDeal.Where(crd=>crd.Disabled==false),
                  c => c.Id,
                  crd => crd.ClientId,
                  (c, crd) => new
                  {
                      c,
                      crd = crd.Where(cr => cr.DateEnd == null || cr.DateEnd > DateTime.Today)
                  })
                  .Where(res =>  res.crd.Count() == 0)
                  .Select(cl => cl.c).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

as you can see in the result selector argument I have kept that condition and then a where clause on the result selector to fetch only those whose client rate deal whose count is 0. However due to some reason I am getting the exception that the LINQ cant be translated. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Use a navigation property `Client.ClientRateDeals`, not GroupJoin. And filtered `Include` if you're in EF core 5.

Comment: @GertArnold I am using EFCore 5 but why am I getting that error ? can I not use GroupJoin for the required result ?

Comment: EF core has very limited support for grouping (GroupBy and GroupJoin).

Comment: @GertArnold but if I dont use groupjoin or any other join how do I achieve this condition that I only have to pick a client if all the clientratedeals inside that client pass some condition ? can you help me with that ?

Comment: What @Gert was saying is that you should have and use *collection navigation property* instead of manual joins. Any reason of not having such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unknown reason (it has nothing in similar with `GroupBy`), LINQ `GroupJoin` operator is not supported in EF Core 3.x, 5.x.

You have to use one of the available alternatives - (1) collection navigation property (preferred) or (2) correlated subquery.

e.g.

(1) In `Client` class define

```cs
public ICollection<ClientRateDeal> ClientRateDeals { get; set; }
```

and use it inside the query

```cs
var query = _context.Client
    .Where(c => c.Disabled==false)
    // vvv
    .Where(c => !c.ClientRateDeals.Any(
        crd => crd.Disabled == false &&
        (crd.DateEnd == null || crd.DateEnd > DateTime.Today)))
    .AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

or (2)

```cs
var query = _context.Client
    .Where(c => c.Disabled==false)
    // vvv
    .Where(c => !_context.ClientRateDeal.Any(crd =>
        c.Id == crd.ClientId &&
        crd.Disabled == false &&
        cr.DateEnd == null || cr.DateEnd > DateTime.Today))
    .AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

In general, instead of

```cs
db.As.GroupJoin(db.Bs, a => a.Id, b => b.AId, (a, Bs) => new { a, Bs })
```

use

```cs
db.As.Select(a => new { a, Bs = db.Bs.Where(b => a.Id == b.AId) })
```

Related github issue (please go vote in order to have a chance to get that implemented):

[Query with GroupBy or GroupJoin throws exception #17068](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068#)

[Query: Support GroupJoin when it is final query operator #19930](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19930)

even though the second is not exactly what we need (we want just  `GroupJoin` to be translated as it was written in correlated subquery syntax shown above).

Comment: Thanks for helping but are you sure that EF Core 5.x doesnt support GroupJoin because there was a query previously written in place of what I have told and it was working fine If you want I can give you that query.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari Yes, I'm 100% sure it is not supported because I had i long fight for it with EF Core team (see the links), which at the end I lost of course - they said *GroupJoin <-> GroupBy equivalence
Due to high cost of pattern matching `GroupJoin` operator, we are not going to add any translation in `GroupJoin` even if equivalent `GroupBy` query would be translated. Customers would be required use `GroupBy` syntax as that is closest representation of what is the SQL.*

Comment: Your provided query is working but there's a problem as I told in my question that if any of the inner entity i.e. Client Rate Deals inside Clients in my case doesn't pass the condition I don't want that client but I just tested and 1 of the clients had 2 CRDs and 1 passed the condition whereas other didn't but I still got that client corresponding to the row for CRD that passed the condition ! How can I correct that ?

Comment: `!Any(...)` should do the job as it is filtering the outer entity (`Client`), not inner entities. `!Any()` is the same as `Count() == 0`, just more performant in general). Do you have additional conditions not shown here?

Comment: No I just want to fetch those clients that have all the client rate deals DateEnd to be in the past or null. if any of the client rate deal has a value in DateEnd that's in future I don't want that client and also the client shouldn't be disabled.

            var query = _context.Client
                        .Where(c => c.Disabled == false)
                        .Where(c => !c.ClientRateDeal.Any(
                        crd => crd.Disabled == false &&
                        (crd.DateEnd == null || crd.DateEnd > DateTime.Today)))
                        .AsNoTracking().ToList();

Comment: Then both queries I suggested are the exact translatable equivalent of your non translatable query., thus should return the same data.